# IIS7 and 301 permanent redirects using the location tag in web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, web-config

I need to setup some 301 permanent redirects in the web.config of an ASP.NET MVC application running under IIS.

The easiest way is to add a tag similar to the one below to the web.config file:

```
 <location path="TheMenu.aspx">
        <system.webServer>
            <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="menus/" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
```

When I go to the site at `http://domain.com/TheMenu.aspx` it redirects me to `http://domain.com/menusxd` instead of `http://domain.com/menus`.

What would be causing this?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197319/asp-net-mvc-how-to-redirect-a-non-www-to-www-and-vice-versa/18160522#18160522

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry I can't help you with `<httpRedirect>` but have you tried / can you use the [IIS7 URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/expand/URLRewrite) module?

Your rule would look something like:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="TheMenu" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="TheMenu.aspx" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="menus/" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

HTHs,
Charles