# ASP.NET Site Redirection help

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am following the code over here https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203216/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072810-1.aspx

to redirect http://somesite.com to http://www.somesite.com

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (Request.Url.Authority.StartsWith("www"))
      return;

   var url = string.Format("{0}://www.{1}{2}",
               Request.Url.Scheme,
               Request.Url.Authority,
               Request.Url.PathAndQuery);

   Response.RedirectPermanent(url, true);
}
```

How can I use this code to handle situations where http://abc.somesite.com should redirect to www.somesite.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you don't know what the values will be ahead of time, you can use substring with indexof for the Url path to parse out the value you want and replace it.
2. If you do know what it is ahead of time, you can always just do Request.Url.PathAndQuery.Replace("abc", "www");

You can also do a dns check as @aceinthehole suggested after you have parsed what you need to make sure you haven't made any mistakes.

assuming you have a string like http://abc.site.com and you want to turn abc into www then you could do something like.

```
string pieceToReplace = Request.Url.PathAndQuery.substring(0, Request.Url.PathAndQuery.IndexOf(".") + 1);

//here I use the scheme and entire url to make sure we don't accidentally replace an "abc" that belongs later in the url like in a word "GHEabc.com" or something.
string newUrl = Request.Url.ToString().Replace(Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + pieceToReplace, Request.Url.Scheme + "://www");

Response.Redirect(newUrl);
```

p.s. I don't remember if the Request.Url.Scheme already has the "://" in it or not so you will need to edit accordingly.

Comment: I do not have access to the DNS. I also do not the values ahead. I just need http://somevalue.somesite.com to be redirectd to www.somsite.com . Can you provide some code please/ thnks

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the best way to handle this would be in the dns record, if you have control of it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it without access to the DNS.  It sounds like you need a wildcard DNS entry:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record

Along with IIS configured without host headers (IP only).  Then you can use code similar to the above to do what you want.

```
if (!Request.Url.Host.StartsWith ("www") && !Request.Url.IsLoopback)
  Response.Redirect('www.somesite.com');
```

Perhaps tighten it up some to prevent wwww.somesite.com from getting through.  Anything that starts with www including wwwmonkeys.somesite.com would get through the above check.  It is just an example.

[asp.net mvc: How to redirect a non www to www and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197319/asp-net-mvc-how-to-redirect-a-non-www-to-www-and-vice-versa)