# How can I redirect my abc.com to www.abc.com?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, web-config

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [asp.net mvc: How to redirect a non www to www and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197319/asp-net-mvc-how-to-redirect-a-non-www-to-www-and-vice-versa)

I want to redirect my site url from abc.com to www.abc.com so that I get standard URL format. 
How can I achieve this? Can any one help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should setup a "HTTP 301 redirect" from abc.com to www.abc.com

Techniques for doing this depend on what kind of HTTP server platform you are using, and are described succinctly in the following section of Wikipedia's page on URL redirection:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx