# How to change URL in MVC c#?

Tags: c#, url, model-view-controller, rewriting

Following is the code in Home Controller :

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult AboutUs()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Following is code in my RouteConfig.cs

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                 "AboutUsPage",
                 "about",
                 new { Controller = "Home", action = "AboutUs", });

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Now If I hit the address "localhost:9731/Home/AboutUs" then It will Hit my AboutUs action in Home Controller. similarly If I hit the address "localhost:9731/about" then It will Hit my AboutUs action in Home Controller beacuse of URL rewriting in RouteConfig.cs.

Question is that How to display "localhost:9731/about" when User hit "localhost:9731/Home/AboutUs" in address bar??. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: I think you have a syntax error `action = "AboutUs",` you need to get rid of that comma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve that would be to make 301 Permanent redirect to the new route. So you could have a redirect controller:

```
public class RedirectController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string redirectToAction, string redirectToController)
    {
        return this.RedirectToActionPermanent(redirectToAction, redirectToController);
    }
}
```

and then configure your legacy route to redirect to the new one:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "AboutUsPage",
        "about",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "AboutUs", });

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "AboutUsLegacy", 
        url: "Home/AboutUs", 
        defaults: new {
            controller = "Redirect",
            action = "Index",
            redirectToAction = "AboutUs",
            redirectToController = "Home" });

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

In this example we have added a new route before the default one which will listen for the legacy route that you want to redirect (`/Home/AboutUs`) and then it will issue the 301 redirect to `/about`

Comment: Thanks. @Darin Dimitrov It works for me. can we implement same for www.xyz.com to xyz.com??

Comment: Sure, one way to achieve that is to have a global `Application_BeginRequest` ASP.NET event that will take care of this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3197446/29407