# How to avoid HOME in the url an show only the view name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to avoid showing Home in the URL and only the name of the view?

I mean if I want to open the view About which is in the Home controller my URL will be like this:
`www.website.com/Home/About`

But I would love to show only
`www.website.com/About`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your route configuration for the Home controller. If you're using Attribute-based routing with the following your Route configuration:

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

You can do the following in your Home controller:

```
// GET: Home
[Route("")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
  ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

  return View();
}

[Route("about")]
public ActionResult About()
{
  ViewBag.Title = "About Page";
  ViewBag.Message = "About Us";

  return View();
}

That will then remove the controller name from the URLs as required.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You should then create a controller called 'About'.
2. Create inside Controller About -> Action "Index".
3. Copy the content from Home/About to About/Index.

If you want to go to more complicated way and it is not highly recommended (according to this [discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3be51d06-b483-4956-be69-f1234381f64a/hide-controller-name-amp-actionmethod-in-url?forum=aspmvc) ) please [see this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41659468/how-to-change-url-in-mvc-c)