# Redirect from non www to www, do I need two app services in azure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, redirect

I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3197446/3952692) solution in redirecting my domain from non www to www. I'm using azure for hosting.

I have created app service for `www.domain.com`

[image]

when I try to access `domain.com` I get this error:

[image]

Should I have to create two app services one for `domain.com` and one for `www.domain.com`? or is there a way to accomplish this using one app service?

Comment: You don't have to create two app services. Have you added `domain.com` hostname mapping in `Custom DNS` sections for your Web App in Azure Portal?

Comment: I just added the `domain.com` in `Custom Domains` and it worked. Thanks. Please post as answer so that it would be helpful for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I have to create two app services one for domain.com and one
>   for www.domain.com? or is there a way to accomplish this using one app
>   service?

No, you don't need two app services to accomplish this.

Assuming you have configured domain mapping correctly in your DNS provider (e.g. GoDaddy), all you need to do is add both `www.domain.com` and `domain.com` in the Hostname mapping in `Custom DNS` section for your Web App in Azure Portal.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do it set it up in the DNS section of your domain provider and add custom domains in App Service in Azure Portal as well:

```
Type   Name    Value
A      @       Ip Address of your App Service ( this will cover your main domain )
TXT    @       yourwebsite.azurewebsites.net ( this will cover your main domain )
CNAME  www     yourwebsite.azurewebsites.net ( this will conver www section)
```

Now in the app service side you need to add the custom bindings.

```
Go to Azure Portal | App Service | settings | custom domains | add host name as below

yourdomain.com
```

Now you have both domain pointing to same App Service.
[More info on step by step guide, I have prepared a post for custom domain check it out.](https://scientistz.com/2017/12/how-to-create-scalable-optimized-wordpress-site-blog-using-azure-mysql-azure-storage-and-azure-cdn-part-5/)