# Azure web app - Godaddy redirect www to non-www

Tags: azure, no-www

I try to redirect my Azure web app from [www.website.com](http://www.website.com) to website.com and I cannot find a way.
I already check many solutions online and follow the steps, like here: [Redirect from non www to www, do I need two app services in azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48731209/redirect-from-non-www-to-www-do-i-need-two-app-services-in-azure)
but no luck.

In go daddy I have:

```
Type   Name    Value
A      @       myIp 
TXT    @       website.azurewebsites.net 
CNAME  www     website.azurewebsites.net
```

and in Azure Portal I set:

-> custom domains

```
website.azurewebsites.net (given by default from azure)
website.com
www.website.com
```

-> TSL/SSL Settings

```
website.com
www.website.com
```

but still, when I go to [www.website.com](http://www.website.com), I see my website but I don't get forward to website.com

Any idea what else could I do/what am I missing?

Comment: You have DNS record in Godady -> A      @       myIp. Is myIp addess of your Azure WebApp?

Comment: yep correct. A record is something like: A @ 3.29.156.12 (made up ip just as example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got in contact with GoDaddy service and they told me that under the hood, GoDaddy use Forward service to deal with www to non-www.
Basically, GoDaddy forward service, has its own server which has no certificate installed. That's my the warning.
SSL certificate are per domain, per server.

Solution: I must redirect at server level, not DNS level if I want the [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com) to work properly while rediretcing to non-www.

Answer (score 0):

You have DNS records in Godady

```
Type   Name    Value
A      @       myIp 
TXT    @       website.azurewebsites.net 
CNAME  www     website.azurewebsites.net
```

Azure WebApp cannot make redirect from [www.website.com](http://www.website.com) to website.com
You can configure domain Redirect in Godaddy

https://www.godaddy.com/help/edit-my-domain-forwarding-19978

https://www.godaddy.com/help/forward-my-domain-12123

Comment: thank you @Andriy Bilous. I did that but unfortunately it made my www.website.com not secure anymore. NO IDEA WHY! 
So before https://www.website.com and https://website.com where working fine, now https://website.com works fine. https://www.website.com give connection not secure -.-

Comment: Have you enabled HTTP -> HTTPS rediection in Azure WebApp?

Comment: Could you please share screen with detailed error?

Comment: there are no errors. You can go to elliotforwater.com and see by your self. https://elliotforwater.com
http://elliotforwater.com
both work properly
http://www.elliotforwater.com -> brings you to https://elliotforwater.com
BUT https://www.elliotforwater.com doesn't bring you to https://ellitoforwater.com

if I try to forward from goDaddy, when I go to https://www.elliotforwater.com I get browser warnings for connection insecure.

Comment: May you please also share your Godaddy Redirect/Forwarding settings?

Comment: Right now I'm not using goDaddy forwarding system, since was giving warning and i was losing users.
I got in contact with GoDaddy service and they told me that under the hood, GoDaddy use Forward service to deal with www to non-www.
GoDaddy forward has its own server which has no certificate installed. That's my the warning.
I must redirect at server level, not DNS level if I want the https://www.... to work properly.